# CGContext - "modulo" drawing?

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, cgcontext

Imagine I want to draw a custom view in a given rectangle (e.g. 100 x 100 pixels). My custom view's contents might be bigger than 100 x 100. Instead having some content not drawn, I'd like to draw all content inside the 100 x 100 area. For example, a point that would normally be located at (125, 140) would now be drawn at point (25, 40).

Is there any way to do this without having to (majorly) modify the drawing code? Keep in mind that I also draw more complex shapes, like bezier paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could scale your drawing space via [CGContextScaleCTM(...)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html).

e.x.

```
CGFloat sx, sy;
sx = self.frame.size.width / desiredWidth;
sy = self.frame.size.height / desiredHeight;

CGContextScaleCTM(context, sx, sy);
```

**EDIT:**

As Codo suggests below, you may be looking for [CGContextTranslateCTM(...)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html) which will offset your context's coordinate space by some x/y value.

Comment: I guess ryyst is rather looking for CGContextTranslateCTM, which can achieve an offset of 100 pixels (rather than scaling the output).

Comment: @Codo, Sam: What I meant with my example was that the points (25, 40) and (125, 140) and (25, 1240) would be drawn at the same spot. That's why I called it "modulo" drawing.

Comment: You could draw your content several times with different offsets and clip it to the target rectangle every time. But overall, this is a strange requirement. Can you a bigger context of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: It's a pretty common thing to do with textures (e.g. making seamless textures, e.g. making textures that wrap to correct start/end points on a model) and in general tiling, backgrounds, etc